# Set restrictions to nodes displayed after submission

Tags: views

I have a content type (*AppointmentApplication*), which can be used from anonymous users; all the information can be viewed by administrator users.

I don't want all the entered information to be shown right after the node submission by anonymous users in the success page. I just want to show a serial number which can be used from users as their application number. When I restrict the access to this content type display, it effects everyone.

> [image: screenshot]

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/project/field_permissions

Comment: @cilefen thanks

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like this is more a job for [Webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform).

While Content Types/Nodes are quite flexible, it's more for building content pages. Your use case sounds more like arbitrary one-time form submission, which is what Webforms is designed for.

Comment: No, i dont need webform, I have already created a form for data entry using content type section. I am facing problems in setting restrictions in the data displayed which are submitted through that form.

Comment: @user3099225 What I'm trying to say is that you're currently facing this issue because content types is the wrong tool for the job. And you will continue to face more issues if you try to continue down this route. I suggest you cut losses and try Webform.

Comment: @user3099225 does Webform provides image select / browse field ?

Comment: @user3099225 If you mean regular file uploads, yes out-of-the-box. If you mean Media Library, the [Media Library Form API Element](https://www.drupal.org/project/media_library_form_element) module adds support to Webform. Do note that Media Library is styled for Drupal's admin themes by default. If you plan to render the form on a non-admin route, you have to style the Media Library interface yourself.